# What do you call a person/thing that is needed to finish the system/project/goals or plans?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person/thing that is needed to finish the system/project/goals or plans?

Without it/him or her, the system/project/goals or plans can never be finished just like the last piece of puzzle.

Comment: Hi @bmercade, welcome to ELU. For single word requests we require people to provide an example sentence to use their word in. You can edit this in by clicking on the word "edit" under your question.

Comment: *Requirement*....

Answer (score 3):

When you say 'last piece of the puzzle,' do you mean it just has to have the meaning of being essential to the puzzle, or it has to be both essential AND the final step chronologically?

You could call something essential and central, potentially a single point of failure, the *[linchpin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/linchpin)* (alternatively spelled *lynchpin*) of the system.

Comment: +1. "Linchpin" was the first word that came to my mind. The next was **"pivotal"** which I have suggested in my [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/303059/150645)

Answer (score 3):

The term ***keystone*** is what came to my mind.

> A stone arch or vault gains its stability from the placement of the keystone, which is often the last one placed. From this architectural meaning, *keystone* also gained the figurative meaning of "central or most important part," or "the one thing upon which everything else depends." Like an actual stone keystone, this type lends stability: "The right to free speech is the *keystone* of all American rights."
>   <sub>[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/keystone)</sub>

Comment: Was just thinking about writing this myself. It's definitely used figuratively to mean "the important part, without which everything falls apart"; but it would be a "central" part rather than a "finishing" part, so remains to be seen whether it works for the OP's situation.

Comment: An actual keystone is usually the last stone set in place.

Comment: :slaps head: Maybe I should actually have read your quote before commenting. It's the perfect word! :D

Comment: *Synonym:* "cornerstone".

Comment: WIkipedia on "cornerstone": "The cornerstone (or foundation stone) concept is derived from the first stone set in the construction of a masonry foundation, important since all other stones will be set in reference to this stone, thus determining the position of the entire structure."  Like a keystone, it's crucial but unlike a keystone, it's the first one laid rather than the last.

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***[pivotal](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pivotal)***

> Of crucial importance in relation to the development or success of something else

[ODO]

***Usage:***

> The contribution from Bob was ***pivotal*** to our project's successful completion!

or

> The implementation of SystemZ was ***pivotal*** to finish the project well before the deadline.

Answer (score 0):

In project planning, something which absolutely *must* be present, or completed, before something else can happen is often called a ['prerequisite'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prerequisite?s=t)

> **adjective**
>
> 1 - required beforehand: 
>   *a prerequisite fund of knowledge.*
>
> **noun**
>
> 2 - something prerequisite: 
>   *A visa is still a prerequisite for travel in many countries.*
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **sine qua non**, defined by [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sine-qua-non) as

> a necessary condition without which something is not possible.